# Responding to Touch events in different locations in an ImageView android

Tags: android, android-imageview, ontouchlistener

I need to be able to display different `Toast` messages to the user based on what object he clicks on inside an image. For example, if we have an image with different types of animals, I need to display the name of the animal based on where the user touches the image.

Would it be possible to add another Views such as `ImageButton`s on top of the `ImageView` at specific locations? The problem here is that some images are big enough and should be added to a `ScrollView`. So would this implementation slow down the app?

So I am asking here exactly at best practices.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Subclass `ImageView` and use custom attributes to define the object locations in the image. See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr) for more info. Then you can handle input events to figure out which object was clicked from within the same class.

Comment: Is it a problem that the images are too big? Have you thought about scaling them down to the size you want?

Comment: @cjnash Yes I thought about it, but maybe it would be better to keep the image big. In addition, the app is considered to run on a tablet as well. Therefore, it is not a good ideas to resize the image here.